# How do you configure Visual studio to enforce HTML5 standards?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm running VS 2010 SP1 w/Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installed.

I've got it setup so I get the nice HTML5/CSS3 intellisense, but what I'm looking for is more detection and notification.

I have quite a few pages that I am converting to the new standards and have been looking for a way to get a quick snapshot of possible changes required.  Does anyone know of an add-on that will show the invalid html as a tick on the scrollbar?

I would like to be able to open a page in VS, and if it picks up any html5 discrepancies to put a dash on the scrollbar.  Is this configurable in VS?

I have been looking around and haven't quite found what I'm looking for yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question and Resharper is an excellent addon, but I would prefer something that was free.

What I found that works well for me is the [Productivity Power Tools Addon](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/).

This addon includes a number of good improvements, but to keep this in context of my original question I would recommend this based on the Enhanced Scroll Bar.

Once installed, your scrollbar will now have little dash marks representing any validations VS catches.

You can enable this in Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > Enhanced Scroll Bar

It works well in Scroll bar mode or Map mode but Full Map Mode made it quite a bit more difficult to spot the recommendations.

[More details about the Enhanced Scroll Bar](http://abhijitjana.net/2011/03/08/track-changes-and-advance-scroll-mode-in-visual-studio-2010/)

Comment: You should have looked at @tsells answer that he posted on December 22, 2012 before you answered you own questions. A Down vote for not giving credit where credit was obviously due!

Comment: And an upvote because tsells' great answer didn't directly solve Kevin's individual problem, but the answer Kevin provided himself did.  ReSharper is probably the better tool - if not spending money isn't a requirement.  You don't know that he didn't upvote it, either.

Comment: @MarkKram I did play around with the trial version of Resharper and it felt like a solid addon, but I'd rather keep it simple and cheap.  The scroll bar I found was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I would take a look at Resharper.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html